# Proving that a polynomial is subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two similar problems which I'm not really sure how to solve.

> a) Let it be $M= \{p \in P_3:p(2)=p(-2)=0 \}$. Is $M$ subspace of $P_3$, and if it is, find it's base and dimension.

I proved that $M$ is a subspace of $P_3$ this way: $p,q \in M ; (\alpha p+ \beta q)(2)=(\alpha p + \beta q)(-2)=\alpha 0+\beta 0 = 0$

But I'm not sure how to write the base? I was thinking something like $\{x^2-2\}$, with dim M = 1?

> b) Let it be $N= \{p \in P_{2017}:p(x)=p(-x), \forall x\in\Bbb R \}$. Is $N$ subspace of $P_{2017}$, and if it is, find it's base and dimension.

Again: $p,q \in N ; (\alpha p+ \beta q)(x)=\alpha p(x) + \beta q(x)=\alpha P(-x)+\beta p(-x) = (\alpha p+ \beta q)(-x)$

And for a base $\{x^2,x^4,x^6,...,x^{2016}\}$, dim N=1008.

Is this a good way of solving these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea for the first problem, but your answer doesn't quite work.  We have $p(x) = x(x^2-4)$ also satisfies that $p(2) = p(-2) = 0$.  These do indeed span the subspace. Any polynomial that satisfies $p(2) = p(-2) = 0$ must have $2$ and $-2$ as roots.  Moreover if this subspace had a dimension of 3, then it would intersect any two dimensional subspace at, at least, a one dimensional subspace.  It's clear $span(1,x)$ has trivial intersection with $M$.

For the second questions, your answer is ,again, almost correct.  This time it's closer to correct though. You want to make sure you have the justification down.  Any polynomial such that $p(x) = p(-x)$ satisfies $p(x) - p(-x) = 0$.  If the polynomial contained any terms with odd exponents, then we'd have an issue.  So these polynomials are precisely those where each term has an even power.  This includes constant polynomials so $dim(N) = 1009$ as you need to include $1$.

Comment: What does P(X) = X(X² - 2) even mean in a space where no multiplication between polynomials is defined???

Comment: Typos, $x^2-4$.

Comment: Nice argument using intersection with $\operatorname{span}(1,x)$! I like that!! Alternatively (more explicitly), if $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ has $p(2)=p(-2)=0$, then $8a+4b+2c+d=-8a+4b-2c+d=0$, hence $8a+2c=4b+d=0$. Then $c=-4a$ and $d=-4b$, so $p(x) = ax(x^2-4)+b(x^2-4) = ap_1(x)+bp_2(x)$ where $p_1(x)=x(x^2-4)=x^3-4x$ and $p_2(x)=x^2-4$.

Comment: @Math_QED I'm not sure what you mean. Multiplication by polynomials is defined. Perhaps you mean it's not a vector space operation for the vector spaces above. I don't see how this is relevant as I'm merely just describing a polynomial with a product.